# How can I say skinned alive in Korean?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, phrase-request

I am looking for a Korean equivalent of the expression in this sentence:

"He'll **skin me alive** if he finds out I'm playing games in the class"
or
"I'll get **skinned** if he finds out I'm playing games in class"

Is there an equivalent Korean expression that can be used humorously?

Comment: Are you only interested in expressions that mean 'skinned', or also others that could be used figuratively in those situations?

Comment: both, if possible; or else, anything is fine

Answer (score 5):

You can use the negative form of the verb [가만두다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=186200) which means:

> 동사 (verb)
>
> 「(object)…을」 건드리거나 상관하지 않고 그대로 두다. (literally) Subject doesn't touch nor care and leave the object be. (to tolerate)
>
> 다시 나쁜 짓 하는 날엔 너를 가만두지 않겠다. (literally) I will never forgive / tolerate you when you do something bad again.

Your example sentence

> He'll skin me alive if he finds out I'm playing games in the class.

could be translated to:

> 내가 수업 중에 게임을 하는 것을 그가 알게 되면 (그는) 나를 (날) 가만두지 않을 거야.

Of course, the literal translation of 'to skin someone alive' is '산 채로 가죽을 벗기다', but it will sound too cruel and harsh if you translate it to

> 내가 수업 중에 게임을 하는 것을 그가 알게 되면 (그는) 나를 (날) 산 채로 가죽을 벗길 거야.

It makes sense, but is neither idiomatic nor natural.

You could use '산 채로 가죽을 벗기다' when you are full of anger and revengeful thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

`I'll get skinned alive if the teacher catches me playing games in class` is an imagery that English speakers *say* idiomatically but don't really envision the *true imagery* of when speaking.

The idiomatic phrase that would *feel* the same would be to simply say `Get caught playing games in class, and (he'll) kill you!`

> 교실에서 게임하다 걸리면 넌 죽을 거다!

Answer (score 0):

1) 그가 나를 사진 찍었다. He took my photo

나는 낙인 찍혔다. I received totally bad reputation

누구 찍었니 ? Who do you vote ?

도끼로 나무를 찍다. I chop a tree with an ax.

2) I think that 찍혔어 is suitable for "He'll skin me alive if he finds
out I'm playing games in the class"

Here "my impression is
 printed in his eyes" is a more correct meaning.

A : 나 선생님한테 완전 찍혔어 I was totally pictured by the teacher.

B : 왜 ? Why ?

A : 수업시간에 잤어. 나를 노려 봤어 He saw me take a nap in his class and gave me a fierce look.

B : 조심해. Be careful  next time.